# How to do math in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to do this:

```
100 - {{ object.article.rating_score }}
```

So for example, the output would be `20` if `{{ object.article.rating_score }}` equaled `80`.

How do I do this at the template level? I don't have access to the Python code.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter:

```
{{ object.article.rating_score|add:"-100" }}
```

Comment: For multiplication and division you can misuse the built-in `widthratio` template tag. To compute a*b use `{% widthratio a 1 b %}`, for a/b use `{% widthratio a b 1 %}`. Only drawback, the results are rounded to an integer before returning. [Using Django’s widthratio template tag for multiplication & division](http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/)

Comment: @Erik that should be its own answer - much better solution.

Comment: Updated link to [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add) in the Docs

Comment: What if I use like this : {{ object.article.rating_score|add:"{% widthratio object.article.rating_score 100 5 %}" }}

Comment: @Daniel Roseman can I add after applying percentage like this:  {{ object.article.rating_score|add:"{% widthratio object.article.rating_score 100 5 %}" }}

Comment: Won't this result in `{{object.article.rating_score}} - 100` instead of `100 - {{object.article.rating_score}}`? If one renders this with `Template('{{ x|add:"-100" }}').render(Context({'x': 80}))`, I get `-20`, not `20`.

Answer (score 42):

Use [django-mathfilters](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters). In addition to the built-in add filter, it provides filters to subtract, multiply, divide, and take the absolute value.

For the specific example above, you would use `{{ 100|sub:object.article.rating_score }}`.

Answer (score 21):

Generally it is recommended you do this calculation in your view. Otherwise, you could use the add filter.

Comment: How you do it inside loop in template?