# How to do math operations in django template?

Tags: django, templates

I want to substract a variable from another variable of the same object in django template

```
{% for object in object_list %}
      {{ object.var1 - object.var2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this results in a `TemplateSyntaxError`. How to do that operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285327/how-to-do-math-in-a-django-template).)

Good way to accomplish this seems to be to use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/). This enables you to perform other math operations in addition to subtraction (add, multiply, divide, absolute value, etc.).

For your problem, this should work:
`{{ object.var1|sub:object.var2 }}`

If you know you will only ever need subtraction, you may find a simpler solution (though I don't think it's worth worrying about).

Comment: Or you can just write your own templatetags and pass variables direct from the templates

Answer (score 5):

Its recommended to use either django view or models to do this kind of math operation. Because django template is used as presentation, and should not have any business logic or calculations. You can simply do the calculation using [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) in queryset. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F
object_list = ModelClass.objects.all().annotate(difference=F('var1') - F('var2'))
```

If you are using a [Generic Display Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/), then put this code in `get_queryset` like this:

```
class YourListView(ListView):
  ...

  def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
     qset = super(YourListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
     return qset.annotate(difference=F('var1') - F('var2'))
```

Then use it template like this:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
      {{ obj.difference }}
{% endfor %}
```